# open source SQL source control plugin for SQL server management studio

Tags: visual-studio, ssms, redgate, source-control-explorer

Please can anyone suggest an open source(free), source control plugin (like Redgate) for SQL server management studio. I know this will be a duplicate but i tried all of them questions and found nothing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this with Visual Studio **"Schema comparison"**.

Tools-> SQL server -> New Schema comparison. In here you can compare the two databases and see who have done changes to it. Hope this helps to someone.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

To enable Source Controlling integration in SQL Server management studio we can use MSSCCI(Microsoft Source Code Controll Interface) provider.But we can only create queries for Source Controlling.Solution is to generate a SQL script of your database and commit it to the Visual Studio team server file directory.Hope this will help you to solve your question.